# Cannot read settings using ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I want to read / write setting information from / to the C# project app.config file at a run-time.
The following attempts fail:

1. `var s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySet"];` s is null
2. `var sect = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("testing.Properties.Settings") as AppSettingsSection;` sect is null

Below is the view on the App.config file internals:

```
configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="testing.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
   <userSettings>
    <testing.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="mySet" serializeAs="String">
            <value>a</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="hisSet" serializeAs="String">
            <value>b</value>
        </setting>
    </testing.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

However, I'm able to read this information through the following call:

```
var prop = Properties.Settings.Default.mySet;
```

Why then the code utilizing ConfigurationManager class fails?

ps. I've got testing.exe.config stored under the same directory as the testing.exe

Comment: It's `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings/testing.Properties.Settings")`, you forgot `userSettings/`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: It worked just for the first debug session. When stepping this line for the next debug session, it returned null. Could the way it's working be correlated to the (re)building of the solution?